# Find String between characters with multiple occurences in Python

Tags: python, string, split

So I want to find a string between 2 characters.
I already did that like this:

```
import re
str = "Please use <cmd> and after that <cmd2>!"
result = re.search('<(.*)>', str)
print(result.group(1)
```

The problem about this is that if I perform it it prints the text between the first < and the last > which is not exactly what I want.

```
cmd> and after that <cmd2
```

But what I rather want is that I get the first occurence "cmd" and then the second occurence "cmd2" seperatly.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Make your pattern non-greedy: `<(.*?)>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the capture group non-greedy, and to get all the occurrences, you should use `re.findall()` rather than `re.search()`:

```py
result = re.findall('<(.*?)>', str)
```

This outputs:

```py
['cmd', 'cmd2']
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like this!